# How do you add a new form layout in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, craueformflow

In my Symfony2 project, I noticed that there are only two layout options for rendering forms:

`form_table_layout.html.twig`
and
`form_div_layout.html.twig`

These both reside in `symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form`, and I would like to add one of my own somewhere in my `app\Resources` directory.

The only issue I'm having, is when I add my new layout file (`form_list_layout.html.twig`) into `app\Resources\views\Form`, Symfony doesn't look for it and just looks in the default location instead (in the Twig directory).

I have tweaked my `config.yml` to tell it to include the new layout, but maybe I'm doing something wrong:

```
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
        resources: ['form_list_layout.html.twig']
```

EDIT: Okay, I've got Symfony2 looking in the right place now, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the rendering of the form (I copied the contents of the table layout file into my new list layout file to test the theory, and my form is still rendering with `<div>` tags instead. This might be caused by the `CraueFormFlowBundle` I'm using, so I'll check it out).

The working `config.yml`:

```
 twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
        resources:
            - ":Form:form_list_layout.html.twig"
```

EDIT 2: Doesn't look like its anything to do with the `CraueFormFlowBundle`, is there anything in my configuration that might be causing it to ignore the global form layout?

EDIT: Actually, it is working. As soon as I changed my layout file to include my list elements instead of the table layout content, it appeared okay.

Comment: You want to add your answer as an answer instead of just editing the question.

Comment: have done, it wasn't working at first hence I never added it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to place it into an `app` subfolder; you can place it in any bundle you want. For example, in my case, I've placed it into `CommonBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig` and activate it in the `config.yml` file as

```
twig:
    form:
        resources: [ 'CommonBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' ]
```

Of course, if you put it into an `app` subfolder, you just omit the bundle name part:

```
twig:
    form:
        resources: [ ':Form:fields.html.twig' ]
```

Comment: cheers, I accepted your answer as it provides a bit more detail

Answer (score 0):

To correctly override a form layout or add a new one, place the file in your `app/Resources/views/Form` directory, and tweak your `config.yml` to something like this...

```
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
        resources:
            - ":Form:form_list_layout.html.twig"
```